# condition for a group to be abelian

Tags: group-theory

I’d like to prove:

> Let $G$ be a group and $m,n$ two relatively prime numbers. If $x^my^m=y^mx^m$ and $x^ny^n=y^nx^n$ for all $x,y\in G$, then $G$ is abelian.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Try it out for $m =2, n = 3$, then for $m = 2, n = 4$, spot the difference, and begin the general proof.